# Change the key of a message in the error bag?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How can I customise the key name in an error bag?

```
foreach ($validator->errors()->messages() as $key => $value) {
```

Changing the key in here is not reflected in the message array.

I cannot also see a setter for the message bag.

So, how can I change the key of a message in the error bag?

Comment: Use laravel request class for validations, And you can easily customize the messages

Comment: I'm not trying to customise the message.